# Facebook Group re-join

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I created a Group for a reunion and did not choose a "administrator" to run the group. Left it open for individuals in the group to add people. I accidentally removed myself from my group (duh) and requested to join again. Who will get this? and let me back in? The group was also removed from my page and I can not edit anything. I am waited to be added but not

Comment: If you know someone personally in the group, send them a PM!

Comment: you can create a new group and add them back

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the only way to do this is to write a request to Facebook staff, describe situation and wait for their reaction.

I see many questions like that on the web with no answers at all and I think no one found a workaround.